# Which FLAG to use to have a single instance of an activity? - android

Tags: android, flags

I am going through the Intent on the android API page but I dont really get which flag to use. I want to set a FLAG to an intent that: if that activity is already launched it is going to bring it back on top without creating a new instance of it. If the activity is not launched then I need a new one to start and brought on top.  What is the right FLAG to use?

Comment: You can find very good documentation about the different flags and your requirement at the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks

Comment: You can set an activity to be singleInstance in the manifest